# How do I properly access the output of my yolo8 model given an input bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
val model = Yolov8mFloat32.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(image)
val output = outputs.outputAsCategoryList

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

I tried to use this sample code in my jetpack compose app, but this particular line causes an error.

`val output = outputs.outputAsCategoryList`

This was the error.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1 mismatch the shape on axis 1`

I think the problem is that it's trying to read a label name somewhere, but I have no clue where it does that. I couldn't quite find a solution for it.

[expected input and output of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkFNi.png)

I tried to get the type of outputs with this line.

`Log.d("output test", outputs::class.qualifiedName!!)`

I got this.

`com.example.insight.ml.Yolov8mFloat32.Outputs`

Yolov8mFloat32 is my tflite file.